# issue KeyStroking in mac OS X vs windows

Tags: java, macos, swing, focus, keystroke

```
   public void keyStrokeActions(){

        screen.setFocusable(true);
        screen.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed SPACE"),"attackAction");
        screen.getActionMap().put("attackAction",attackAction);

        screen.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed P"),"pauseAction");
        screen.getActionMap().put("pauseAction",pauseAction);
   }
```

I am trying to make this work, as you can see it's a simple keyStroking where screen's a JPanel. The actions attackAction and pauseAction are defined before as global variables.

In windows everything works perfectly, however in mac it doesn't. No matter the key I press, it doesn't react. I also tried

```
  screen.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(' ',0),"attackAction");
```

and

```
  screen.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(' '),"attackAction");
```

But I couldn't make it work. Not with ' ' or 'P' or any other sort of char. Anyone could bring some light?

Thanks,
Sergi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time working on it, I found out that if it worked on Mac it didn't on windows, and if it worked in windows it didn't on Mac. So, basically, java's multi-platform as long as the virtual machine's fine with it.